# option:hover style not working in Chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome

```
option:hover {
    background-color: #804000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Style not reflecting on Chrome but working properly in Firefox and IE

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2404/nd7Lfojv/2/)

Comment: Press Ctrl + f5. It will refresh the browser cache. Then Check.

Comment: Consider adding a code snippet of where this CSS is getting used.

Answer (score 0):

Styling the hover of options only works in browsers where the options are actually implemented as elements (or similar).

There is nothing in the standards that specifies how a `select` element should display the options (unless the `size` attribute is used). In a desktop browser typically some form of dropdown menu is used, in a mobile browser the options are typically displayed in a completely different way.

In some browsers the options in the dropdown are implemented using elements (or similar), that allows the browser to support some styling and events that are available on regular elements.